# How can I add a little code block instream with text?

Tags: code

I would like to add a little code block in line with paragraph text. For example:

In order to do this just run the [code block] command in your terminal.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `listings` package provides a command for inline code snippets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language = C++}
\begin{document}
In order to do this just run the
\lstinline!#include <iostream>! command
command in your terminal.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with Code snippet]

Instead of the exclamation mark you could use any character as delimiter, as long as it does not appear in the code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

The [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package offers you `\mintinline`; since it uses Pygments, its highlighting quality is superb:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
You can use \mintinline{python}{def boring(args = None):} and some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice +1, one off-topic nitpick for python: it would be `def boring(args=None)` according to PEP8.